# Trying to coin a new word, and trying to stay true to Latin Sandhi phonological rules

Tags: morphology, phonology

I'm writing a paper and I'm proposing a couple of new latin terms:

1. alterpersona
2. realterpersona

or to break them down into components

1. alter-persona
2. re-alter-persona

I'm wondering about the sandhi rules for latin. I couldn't find anything online. I'm suspicious that putting "re" next to "alter" as a single word might change the vowels between the "r" and the "l." Can anyone share some wisdom?

Answer (score 3):

Latin doesn’t regularly elide the e in re-. The prefix re- has a variant red-; this is sometimes found before vowels, but re- can also be found before vowels.

If you’re trying to coin a word based on Latin tendencies, I think the biggest issue would not be sandhi of the parts, but how the parts are put together (and which parts you use). The compounding strategy that you seem to be using to form “(re)alterpersona” does not feel very Latin to me (but I’m not strong enough in Latin to be sure, or to explain why I feel this way).

Perhaps you could consider using Greek, which has a greater abundance of compound words.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I will probably have to also coin the terms in greek at some point as I'm doing this in a theological context. For now I'm sticking to latin however

Comment: I also feel iffy about how I'm joining the words. I basically want to squish "alter persona" into a single word to convey "an other person" (think 'alter-ego'), and then do it again by adding "re" (or something else) to it which conveys the repetition of "yet another person"

Comment: If you can guess the context of what I'm trying to do (theologically speaking), I'll buy you a virtual beer :)